# cleaning big data using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have to clean a input data file in python. Due to typo error, the datafield may have strings instead of numbers. I would like to identify all fields which are a string and fill these with NaN using pandas. Also, I would like to log the index of those fields.

One of the crudest way is to loop through each and every field and checking whether it is a number or not, but this consumes lot of time if the data is big.

*My csv file contains data similar to the following table:*

```
Country  Count  Sales
USA         1   65000
UK          3    4000
IND         8       g
SPA         3    9000
NTH         5   80000
```

....
Assume that i have 60,000 such rows in the data.

Ideally I would like to identify that row IND has an invalid value under SALES column. Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: A loop over the file with `60000` rows really shouldn't take very long.  It seems to me that the time spent with that method would be hardly noticeable.  Can you show what you've attempted as well as benchmarks demonstrating that it really is a significant load for your computer?

Comment: If it takes a longer time then use the multiprocessing module, but it really shouldn't take longer than a few seconds, of course depending on the number of lines that you need to edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `na_values` argument to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

> `na_values` : list-like or dict, default `None`
>             Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values

```
df = pd.read_csv('city.csv', sep='\s+', na_values=['g'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  Country  Count  Sales
0     USA      1  65000
1      UK      3   4000
2     IND      8    NaN
3     SPA      3   9000
4     NTH      5  80000
```

Using [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html#pandas.Series.isnull), you can select only those rows with NaN in the `'Sales'` column, or the `'Country'` series:

```
In [3]: df[pd.isnull(df['Sales'])]
Out[3]: 
  Country  Count  Sales
2     IND      8    NaN

In [4]: df[pd.isnull(df['Sales'])]['Country']
Out[4]: 
2    IND
Name: Country
```

*If it's already in the DataFrame you could use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to convert those strings which are numbers into integers (using [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)):*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Count': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 8, 3: 3, 4: 5}, 'Country': {0: 'USA', 1: 'UK', 2: 'IND', 3: 'SPA', 4: 'NTH'}, 'Sales': {0: '65000', 1: '4000', 2: 'g', 3: '9000', 4: '80000'}})

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
  Country  Count  Sales
0     USA      1  65000
1      UK      3   4000
2     IND      8      g
3     SPA      3   9000
4     NTH      5  80000

In [13]: df['Sales'] = df['Sales'].apply(lambda x: int(x) 
                                                  if str.isdigit(x)
                                                  else np.nan)

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  Country  Count  Sales
0     USA      1  65000
1      UK      3   4000
2     IND      8    NaN
3     SPA      3   9000
4     NTH      5  80000
```

Comment: nice. why did you comment out the read_csv code? It seems to work.

Comment: @Monir uncommented, and commented the `to_dict()`. Although, `apply` is the important bit of my answer (weirdly no other answers seem to use it).

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as PD

filename = os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/data.csv')
df = PD.DataFrame(
        np.genfromtxt(
            filename, delimiter = '\t', names = True, dtype = '|O4,<i4,<f8'))
print(df)
```

yields

```
  Country  Count  Sales
0     USA      1  65000
1      UK      3   4000
2     IND      8    NaN
3     SPA      3   9000
4     NTH      5  80000
```

and to find the country with `NaN` sales, you could compute

```
print(y['Country'][np.isnan(y['Sales'])])
```

which yields the `pandas.Series`:

```
2    IND
Name: Country
```

Comment: I think that predicting the dtype may not be possible/reasonable on larger dataframes, especially if there were many more columns than in this toy example...

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the 'sales' string to an `int`, if it is well formed then it goes on, if it is not it will raise a `ValueError` which we catch and replace with the place holder.

```
bad_lines = []

with open(fname,'rb') as f:
    header = f.readline()
    for j,l in enumerate(f):
        country,count,sales = l.split()
        try:
            sales_count = int(sales)
        except ValueError:
            sales_count = 'NaN'
            bad_lines.append(j)
        # shove in to your data structure
        print country,count,sales_count
```

you might need to edit the line that splits the line (as your example copied out as spaces, not tabs).  Replace the print line, with what ever you want to do with the data.  You probably need to relpace 'NaN' with the pandas NaN as well.

Comment: `int(sales)` should give the same thing as `int(sales.strip())` (`int` doesn't care about whitespace)

Comment: Also, you could probably do `country,count,sales = l.split()` or possibly `country,count,sales = l.split(None,2)`

Comment: @mgilson awesome, python is smarter than I thought (again)

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = open('file.csv')
filename.readline()

for line in filename:
    currentline = line.split(',')
    try:
        int(currentline[2][:-1])
    except:
        print currentline[0], currentline[2][:-1]
```

IND g

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use a regex:

```
import re

ss = '''Country  Count  Sales
USA   ,      3  , 65000
UK    ,      3  ,  4000
IND   ,      8  ,     g
SPA   ,     ju  ,  9000
NTH   ,      5  , 80000
XSZ   ,    rob  ,    k3'''

with open('fofo.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(ss)

print ss
print

delimiter = ','

regx = re.compile('(.+?(?:{0}))'
                  '(( *\d+?)| *.+?)'
                  '( *(?:{0}))'
                  '(( *\d+?)| *.+?)'
                  '( *\r?\n?)$'.format(delimiter))

def READ(filepath, regx = regx):
    with open(filepath,'rb+') as f:
        yield f.readline()
        for line in f:
            if None in regx.match(line).group(3,6):
                g2,g3,g5,g6 = regx.match(line).group(2,3,5,6)
                tr = ('%%%ds' % len(g2) % 'NaN' if g3 is None else g3,
                      '%%%ds' % len(g5) % 'NaN' if g6 is None else g6)
                modified_line = regx.sub(('\g<1>%s\g<4>%s\g<7>' % tr),line)
                print ('------------------------------------------------\n'
                       '%r with aberration\n'
                       '%r modified line'
                       % (line,modified_line))
                yield modified_line
            else:
                yield line

with open('modified.txt','wb') as g:
    g.writelines(x for x in READ('fofo.txt'))
```

result

```
Country  Count  Sales
USA   ,      3  , 65000
UK    ,      3  ,  4000
IND   ,      8  ,     g
SPA   ,     ju  ,  9000
NTH   ,      5  , 80000
XSZ   ,    rob  ,    k3

------------------------------------------------
'IND   ,      8  ,     g\r\n' with aberration
'IND   ,      8  ,   NaN\r\n' modified line
------------------------------------------------
'SPA   ,     ju  ,  9000\r\n' with aberration
'SPA   ,    NaN  ,  9000\r\n' modified line
------------------------------------------------
'XSZ   ,    rob  ,    k3' with aberration
'XSZ   ,    NaN  ,   NaN' modified line
```