# why loading dataframe from csv turned all the ndarray to string?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which saved as `csv` in this way:

```
df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
```

The dataframe values are `ndarray` type, for example:

```
type(df.iloc[0][2]) = ndarray
```

I'm reading the csv file as:

```
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", sep=',')ndarray
```

And the values turned from ndarray to string:

```
type(df.iloc[0][2]) = string
```

How can I read the dataframe from csv, while preserving the type (`ndarray`) of each item ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cleaning big data using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867294/cleaning-big-data-using-python)

Comment: look at the csv.  Do you see arrays,or the `str` representation of arrays?

Comment: Saving that kind of dataframe to csv is a bad idea.  csv is a 2d table representation.  Your frame has an embedded 3rd dimension.  The arrays are not saved in a way that can be easily turned back into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `dtype` or `converters` arguments in the `read_csv` function, see [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)